# Online note taking

Tags: applications, text-editor

I need to be able to save text (like url, sms, etc) on my android phone which can also be viewed on the Internet through a URL.  Right now I use Google Drive (which takes time) or Facebook chat (by sending text to s friend and then copying the same.)

App suggestions are welcome as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried [Evernote](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.evernote)?  You can create notes in the phone and read on the Web, and create on the web and view on your phone.  The sync works perfectly!

Comment: There's also Springpad for similar functionality.

Comment: Or catch notes.